# Reference request for the list of nilpotent subgroups of SU(2)?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups

It's not  hard to show that all non-abelian nilpotent subgroups of $SU(2)$ are actually finite and in fact are conjugate to one of the generalized quaternion groups of order a power of two, $$Q_{2^n} = \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} e^{\pi i/2^{n-2}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-\pi i/{2^{n-2}}} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle.$$

Does someone know of a reference for this fact?

Comment: All finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ have been known for well over a century, so it only the fact that nilpotence implies finiteness that you need a reference for.

Comment: I'd appreciate a reference for the classification of the finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ too, if you know of one, @GeoffRobinson.

Comment: The introduction of this dissertation -- https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/McKay/Carrasco_Project.pdf -- discusses the finite subgroups of $SU(2)$. The author attributes this work to Klein, and gives a reference.

Comment: Thanks @NickGill! The reference to Klein is to his famous *Lectures on the Icosahedron*! I guess I now have to confess to not having read them.